# Correct use of the case operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, menu, callback, case

I'm trying to use the case command to go to a specific URL depending on the menu item clicked.  The following code was graciously provided as an example but I keep getting an unexpected end of script error.

My goal is to get the correct code so that depending on the four menu items, you will be directed to the corresponding URL.

Here is the Code:

```
<div id="page3" class="page">
  <div class="form">

    <div class="text">4 Item Menu</div>
    <div class="selection" id="fs_3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="plugin/react-with-addons.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="plugin/react-dom.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script src="plugin/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  new CA_select({
        selector: document.getElementById('fs_3'),
        iconColor: '#fff',
        bgColor: '#00BCD4',
        items: [{
            class: "fa-thumbs-up"
          },
          {
            class: "fa-thumbs-down"
          },
          {
            class: "fa-arrow-right"
          },
          {
            class: "fa-arrow-left"
          },
        ],
        callback: true,
        change: (ret) => {
          switch (ret) {
            case "0":
              window.location.assign("https://www.url1.com");
              break;
            case "1":
              window.location.assign("https://www.url2.com");
              break;
            case "2":
              window.location.assign("https://www.url3.com");
              break;
            case "3":
              window.location.assign("https://www.url4.com");
              break;
          }
        }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: *case* is not an operator, it's a [*keyword*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-Keyword) that signifies the start of a [*CaseBlock*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-CaseBlock), which is part of a [*switch Statement*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-switch-statement) and contains [*CaseClauses*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-CaseClauses). ;-)

Comment: Understood, thank you for the clarification.  Can you help me with the answer though :).

Comment: You are missing a closing `})`, a reasonable code editor (and close attention to indenting) should help with balancing brackets and braces.

Comment: That did it!  So weird, Dreamweaver normally complains but this time nothing.